# Single word for expressing underwear marks on skin

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

I'm looking for a single-worded or a slang term for expressing those marks. I've googled a bit but it did not help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Artist Justin Alexander Bartels has a photograph series titled [Impression](http://www.justinalexanderbartels.com/portfolio/G0000vjStQaMIBw0) based upon these marks.

I would have said "indentations".

For example:

> ...pull an Amanda Lepore and take off all your clothes immediately once you get to the set (optional: bring a loose robe), so you don't have lines to retouch from **waistband indentations**, sock marks, etc. [Suck Less: Where There's a Willam, There's a Way](https://books.google.com/books?id=bg9GDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT108&dq=waistband%20indentations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTx9zi7fbQAhUCiZAKHVTVCYYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=waistband%20indentations&f=false)

and

> She pulls the pajama bottoms down an inch, just far enough to expose the **indentations** left by their elastic waistband. [Blow Fly: Scarpetta](https://books.google.com/books?id=SFlSRgO8WusC&pg=PT279&lpg=PT279&dq=%22the%20indentations%20left%20by%20their%20elastic%20waistband%22&source=bl&ots=RiwGYb05zb&sig=Ay57HocPBkoT5sVafU2H2-rXpb4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6wpvp7vbQAhVBhZAKHehnAd4Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20indentations%20left%20by%20their%20elastic%20waistband%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***imprints*** (check ODO example below).

ODO:

> **[imprint](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/imprint)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A mark or outline made by pressing something on to a softer substance
>
> ‘A red imprint marked my waist where my stockings' elastic had
>   pressed.’