# Is there a scientific term for sock marks?

Tags: synonyms, science

I'm trying to find more information about the marks that tight clothes leave on my skin. Is there a scientific term for them? It seems that people most commonly call them sock marks, but I think there must be a generic term for marks left by clothes.

Comment: Sock marks? Sure, [*periorbital hematoma*](http://c8.alamy.com/comp/C2YTY4/close-up-of-a-man-with-a-black-eye-C2YTY4.jpg). ;)

Comment: @DanBron: Nice try but I meant the indentations on the skin which usually disappear overnight or within a couple of hours. :-)

Comment: I know, my first comment socked.

Comment: Nah, I think it was a puntastic joke.

Comment: 'There must be a term ...' isn't always true. There are terms for when there are such lexical gaps or lacunas.

Comment: *Imprint* seems to be what folks have come up with when pressed.  http://www.complex.com/style/2012/01/rise-and-sigh-bed-linens-that-imprint-words-on-your-skin

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363635/single-word-for-expressing-underwear-marks-on-skin.

Comment: Science needs this term. Lack of a scientific term for this has been holding science back for far too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pitting edema:

> " Any form of pressure, such as from the elastic in socks, can induce pitting with this type of edema"  [MedicineNet.com](http://www.medicinenet.com/edema/page2.htm)

Edema:

> "The accumulation of excess fluid in a fluid compartment. Formerly called dropsy and hydrops" [TheFreedictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/pitting+edema)

Comment: This only applies when there's an underlying medical condition. Pitting edema is when your flesh becomes like that of [Stretch Armstrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretch_Armstrong) (I had it after my twin pregnancy—totally freaky). It's not the same as regular sock marks. At all.

Comment: @1006a  the citation includes these words: " Almost everyone who wears socks all day will have mild pitting edema by the end of the day." And, I tried to get a cite for postpartum edema as being called "pitting" but I failed. thank you for the comment. If you have more please relay it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember hearing on a radio program about "new" words that an African language was the only one that had a specific word for the marks left by tight elastic; unfortunately I can't remember the word.The language was from SE Africa.

Comment: How is this an answer?