# Suitable word to express the sign created by the pressure of a rope on muscle

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, vocabulary

Is there any single word to express the **sign on muscle created by the pressure of a strong rope**?

What would be the noun form? I mean the name of the Sign and the name of this process too.

And what would be the verb form? As elaborately I can say, *cutting muscle by rope's pressure or whatever*!(not sure whether it makes any sense or not)

Comment: **Imprint** is a word that can be used to refer to the condition of something leaving its shape or texture on the skin (nor muscle; muscle lies beneath the skin) by pressure effect. *His skin bore the **imprint** of the strong rope for several hours.* (please Google 'skin imprint' and see images for examples.) It can be used as verb also: the strong rope ***imprinted itself*** (verb) on his skin, and ***the imprint*** (noun) lasted several hours.

Comment: Ligature marks.

Comment: @PhilSweet and the verb form please?

Comment: 'Ligature marks' as suggested by Phil Sweet is the **exact scientific term** used in forensic medicine. The word *ligate* (which means "to tie") is the verb form, but it means 'tying something' and does not specifically refer to *ligature marks* which is the technical term for rope-burns (pressure / friction / constriction injuries) or imprints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single word for expressing underwear marks on skin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363635/single-word-for-expressing-underwear-marks-on-skin)

Comment: The verb in *ligature mark* is *mark*: "the rope **marked** his skin". If that doesn't sound severe enough, there are lots of other options, starting with your own idea: *the rope **cut** (into) his skin/wrists/hands".

Answer (score 2):

**Imprint** is a word that can be used to refer to the condition of something leaving its shape or texture on the skin (not muscle; muscle lies beneath the skin) by **pressure effect.**

> Definition of imprint [NOUN]  something imprinted or printed: such as
>   a :  a mark or depression made by pressure(...)
>
> Definition of imprint
>   [transitive verb] 1: to mark by or as if by pressure.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imprint

> His skin bore the **imprint** (noun) of the strong rope for several hours.

(please Google 'skin imprint' and see images for examples.)

It can be used as verb also:

> the strong rope **imprinted** itself (verb) on his skin, and the *imprint* (noun) lasted several hours.

Answer (score 1):

***indentation***  noun (freedictionary.com) [The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indentation)

**The visible effect made on a surface by pressure:**

*impress, impression, imprint, indent, mark, print, stamp.*

Comment: +1 for a nice and simple answer providing many options for OP!